# Is it possible to describe non-JavaScript files in JSDoc?

Tags: node.js, express, jsdoc

I'm documenting a NodeJS + Express project and I'd like to be able to reference specific LESS views and Jade templates from the JavaScript files. For example:

```
/** Displays the homepage using the {@link views/index} view. Requires {@link stylesheets/news.less} for styling the news section. */
exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render( 'index', { title: 'Welcome' } );
};
```

In addition to being able to link to non-JS files, I would like for them to appear in the sidebar along with everything else.

I could just put a header in every `.less`/`.jade` file and tell JSDoc to parse them through the project's `conf.json`, but... I don't want JSDoc to *actually* parse them because that would be a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got around this by creating a `views.jsdoc` file inside my `views` directory, and a `stylesheets.jsdoc` file inside my `stylesheets` directory. In the `.jsdoc`s, I declared my LESS and JADE files as externals, each in its own block comment. Example:

**views.jsdoc**

```
/**
 * The homepage view. Uses the {@link external:views/news} widget to render each news article.
 * @external views/index
 * @extends external:views/layout
 */

/**
 * The news widget.
 * @external views/news
 */

/**
 * The base layout from which all other views inherit from.
 * @external views/layout
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in `commentsOnly` plugin that ships with JSDoc3 (though, that messes up line numbers):

```
// jsdoc.json
{
  "plugins": ["plugins/commentsOnly"]
}
```

and then `jsdoc src -d docs -R README.md -c jsdoc.json`

---

You could also write your own plugin that does the same thing, but preserves newlines:

```
// jsdocPlugin.js
var commentPattern = /\/\*\*[\s\S]+?\*\//g,
    notNewLinePattern = /[^\n]/g,
    extname = require('path').extname,
    extension = '.js',
    comments;

exports.handlers = {
  beforeParse: function (e) {
    if (extension === extname(e.filename)) {
      comments = e.source.match(commentPattern);
      e.source = comments ? e.source.split(commentPattern).reduce(function(result, source, i) {
        return result + source.replace(notNewLinePattern, '') + comments[i];
      }, '') : e.source.replace(notNewLinePattern, '');
    }
  }
};

// jsdoc.json
{
  "plugins": ["jsdocPlugin.js"]
}
```

and then `jsdoc src -d docs -R README.md -c jsdoc.json`

---

I wrote a small wrapper around JSDoc, that does this and you can use programmatically in Node.js - [Documentation](http://thealjey.github.io/webcompiler/Documentation.html)